# lodown - Error in function: server response timeout

Tags: r

Na tentativa de utilizar o pacote `lodown`, obtenho um  erro:

```
pns_cat <- get_catalog( "pns",
                output_dir = file.path(path.expand( "~" ), "PNS"))

building catalog for pns

Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : server response timeout
```

Alguém deparou com o mesmo erro antes?

Comment: Isso é um erro do servidor. Tem a certeza que está ativo?

Comment: Ahhnnn... Entendi... Obrigada, Rui... de fato, não sei se o servidor está ativo... Você pode me dar dicas de como eu faço pra descobrir?